# themes installation in wordpress - visibility issue

Tags: wordpress

[Wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com) doesn't allow free members to upload or customize the theme,

whereas in wordpress.org one can login and then upload a theme.

I want to know whether the theme uploaded through wordpress.org will be visible to all or only to the user who uploaded it.

Can the user use the theme in his wordpress.com blog.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No wordpress.com doesn't allow.